# Could I combine wildcard and fulltext search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

For example, I have some titles data in Elasticsearch likes this,
`gamexxx_nightmare`,
`gamexxx_little_guy`

Then I input
`game` => search out `gamexxx_nightmare` and `gamexxx_little_guy`
`little guy` => search out `gamexxx_little_guy` ?

first I think I will use a wildcard to make `game` match `gamexxx`, the second it is fulltext search?
How to combine them in one DSL??

Comment: any luck and let me know if need any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Jaspreet's answer is right but doesn't combine both the requirements in one query DSL as asked by OP in his question **How to combine them in one DSL??**.

It's an enhancement to Jaspreet's solution as I am also not using the wild-card and even avoiding the n-gram analyzer which is too costly(increases the index size) and requires re-indexing if requirement changes.

One Search query to combine both the requirement can be done as below:

### Index mapping

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_underscore" -->note this
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_underscore": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "_ => \\u0020"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index your sample docs

```
{
   "title" : "gamexxx_little_guy"
}

And

{
   "title" : "gamexxx_nightmare"
}
```

### Single Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ --> note this
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "prefix": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "value": "game"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "query": "little guy"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
 {
        "_index": "so-46873023",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.2814486,
        "_source": {
           "title": "gamexxx_little_guy"
        }
     }
```

**Important points:**

1. The first part of the query is `prefix` query, which would match the `game` in both the documents. (This would avoid costly regex).
2. The second part is allowing the full-text search, to enable this, I used custom analyzer which replaces the `_` with whitespace, so you don't need expensive (n-grams in index) and simple match query would fetch the results.
3. Above query, returns result matching both the criteria, you can change the high level, bool clause to `should` from `must` if, you want to return matching any criteria.

Answer (score 1):

[NGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) have better performance than wildcards. For wild card all documents have to be scanned to see which match the pattern. Ngrams break a text in small tokens. Ex Quick Foxes will stored as [ Qui, uic, ick, Fox, oxe, xes ] depending on min_gram and max_gram size.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "little guy"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to go with wildcard only then you can search on not_analyzed string. This will handle spaces between words

```
"wildcard": {
      "text.keyword": {
        "value": "*gamexxx*"
      }
}
```

Comment: OP asked a single query and in your second example, you are using `wildcard` query, which is overkill, have a look at my answer and feel free to ask, if any doubts.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Thanks for the comments, will go through your answer

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja can you point to good resources to learn elastic search  in deep. I have intermediate level knowledge  of it

Comment: Sure, you can refer to https://opster.com/ this site, has a lot of detailed blogs, written by search experts, architects and especially helpful if you are using ES in scalable, high throughput, low latency systems.

Comment: Some of my written blogs are https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/how-to-use-elasticsearch-slow-log-search-queries/  and https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-search-latency-burst-of-search-traffic-guide/

Comment: You can also check https://opster.com/analysis/ if you want to go deep into the ES logs and architecture.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja  thanks for the valuable input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209093/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-jaspreet-chahal).